# Why is this question about differences between two methods too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

I noticed that [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536551/rhino-mocks-difference-between-generatestubt-generatemockt/) has been closed as 'Too broad'

I obviously don't understand something about the meaning of 'too broad' as the question seems fine to me.

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.

I can't see that there are too many possible answers as there are specific differences between the use cases for Stubs and Mocks in Rhino, and I don't think that explaining those differences is too long (my answer isn't that long)

So what are the specific reasons for closing this particular question?

Comment: A moderator tends to step in like this when a question constantly draws flags.  It is not much of a question, the OP gives no cue whatsoever to give an answerer a lead to focus on.  And it asks for "a suitable example", one he never actually got.  Edit the question if you think you can do a better job asking this.

Comment: The actual question was 'Where should one use Stub over Mock method or otherwise?' which I thought was answerable and there was no need for an example, despite the request. Would editing it to improve the english and remove the request for an example make it narrow enough?